# Pandas Passing Variable Names into Column Name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains 13 different column names, I have separated these headings into two lists. I now want to perform different operations on each of these lists.

Is it possible to pass column names into pandas as a variable? My code at the moment can loop through the list fine but i am having trouble trying to pass the column name into the function

**Code**

```
CONT = ['age','fnlwgt','capital-gain','capital-loss']
#loops through columns
for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
    if column_name in CONT:
        X = column_name
        print(df.X.count())
    else:
        print('')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `subset` created from `list` `CONT`:

```
print df
  age fnlwgt  capital-gain
0   a    9th             5
1   b    9th             6
2   c    8th             3

CONT = ['age','fnlwgt']

print df[CONT]
  age fnlwgt
0   a    9th
1   b    9th
2   c    8th

print df[CONT].count()
age       3
fnlwgt    3
dtype: int64

print df[['capital-gain']]
   capital-gain
0             5
1             6
2             3
```

Maybe better as `list` is `dictionary`, which is created by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df[CONT].count().to_dict()
print d
{'age': 3, 'fnlwgt': 3}
print d['age']
3
print d['fnlwgt']
3
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows(): 
    if column_name in CONT:
        print(df[column_name].count()) 
    else: 
        print('')
```

edit:

To answer your question more precisely:
You can use variables to select cols in 2 ways: `df[list_of_columns]` will return a DataFrame with the subset of cols in `list_of_columns`. `df[column_name]` will return the Series for `column_name`

Comment: Unless you put `else: print('')` on a new line, you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Just another small thing, if I wanted to add the count value to a list which was named after the column name, how would i do that?

Comment: @JJSmith: jezrael gave a pretty good answer. I agree a dictionary would better solve that problem.

feel free to upvote and/or mark an answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway +1 for you answer

Answer (score 1):

The following will print the count of each column in the dataframe if it is a subset of your CONT list.

```
CONT = ['age', 'fnlwgt', 'capital-gain', 'capital-loss']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2), columns=CONT[:2])

>>> df
        age    fnlwgt
0  0.079796  0.736956
1  0.120187  0.778335
2  0.698782  0.691850
3  0.421074  0.369500
4  0.125983  0.454247
```

Select the subset of columns and perform a transform.

```
>>> df[[c for c in CONT if c in df]].count()
age       5
fnlwgt    5
dtype: int64
```